# get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR) returning 12 hr time. Java

Tags: java, class

I searched on the forum and others had the same issue however the solutions did not work for me. I have two problems. I can't get it to display am_pm correctly and GregorianCalendar.HOUR is returning a 24 hour value instead of 12.

here is my code:

```
package lab11;

import java.util.*;
public class Lab11 {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar time = new GregorianCalendar(); //create new gregorian calendar object
    int month = time.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH); // create variables
    int year = time.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    int DOM = time.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int DOW = time.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int hour = time.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR);
    int minute = time.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE);
    int second = time.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
    long setMill = 1234567898765L;
    System.out.println(hour);
    String dayofw = "";
    int am_pm = time.get(GregorianCalendar.AM_PM);
    switch (am_pm) {
        case  Calendar.AM:
            System.out.println("AM");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("PM");
            break;
       }
    if (hour == 0){
        hour = 12;
    }

    switch(DOW){ //switch statement to translate numeric value of DOW to string value
        case 1: dayofw = "Sunday";
            break;
        case 2: dayofw = "Monday";
            break;
        case 3: dayofw = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 4: dayofw = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 5: dayofw = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 6: dayofw = "Friday";
            break;
        case 7: dayofw = "Saturday";
            break;

    }
    if (minute >= 0 && minute <= 9){ //add an extra 0 infront of minutes for formatting
    System.out.println("Today's date is " +  (month + 1) + "/" + (DOM) + "/" + year);
    System.out.println("Today's day is " + dayofw + ", and the time is " + hour + ":0" + minute + (am_pm == Calendar.AM ? "am" : "pm") + " and " + second + " seconds" );
    System.out.println("Today's date in MILLISECONDS = " + time.getTimeInMillis() + "\n");
    }
    else{ //if minutes are 10 or above don't add a 0 infront of minutes
    System.out.println("Today's date is " +  (month + 1) + "/" + (DOM) + "/" + year);
    System.out.println("Today's day is " + dayofw + ", and the time is " + hour + ":" + minute + (am_pm == Calendar.AM ? "am" : "pm")+ " and " + second + " seconds" );
    System.out.println("Today's date in MILLISECONDS = " + time.getTimeInMillis() + "\n");   
    }
    GregorianCalendar setTime = new GregorianCalendar(); //create object for the set date
    setTime.setTimeInMillis(setMill); //set time in milliseconds to the set value
    month = setTime.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH); //update values for variables
    year = setTime.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    DOM = setTime.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int DOW2 = setTime.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    switch(DOW2){
        case 1: dayofw = "Sunday";
            break;
        case 2: dayofw = "Monday";
            break;
        case 3: dayofw = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 4: dayofw = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 5: dayofw = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 6: dayofw = "Friday";
            break;
        case 7: dayofw = "Saturday";
            break;

    }

    hour = setTime.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR);
    minute = setTime.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE);
    second = setTime.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
    int am_pm2 = time.get(GregorianCalendar.AM_PM);


     if (minute >= 0 && minute <= 9){ //add an extra 0 infront of minutes for formatting
    System.out.println("The set date is " + (month) + "/" + (DOM) + "/" + year);
    System.out.println("The set day is " + dayofw + ", and the time is " + hour + ":0" + minute + (am_pm2 == Calendar.AM ? "am" : "pm") + " and " + second + " seconds" );
    System.out.println("The set date in MILLISECONDS = " + setMill);
    }
    else{ //if minutes are 10 or above don't add a 0 infront of minutes
    System.out.println("The set date is " + (month) + "/" + (DOM) + "/" + year);
    System.out.println("The set day is " + dayofw + ", and the time is " + hour + ":" + minute + (am_pm2 == Calendar.AM ? "am" : "pm") + " and " + second + " seconds" );
    System.out.println("The set date in MILLISECONDS = " + setMill);  
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you take the time to have a read of the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR), you will find that

> HOUR
>  Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the
>   morning or afternoon.

In fact what you really want is `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`

> HOUR_OF_DAY
>  Field number for get and set indicating the hour of
>   the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at
>   10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

`GregorianCalendar.AM_PM` is a field value that you pass to `Calendar.get` and will return either `Calendar.AM` or `Calendar.PM`...

**Updated with example**

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
int month = time.get(Calendar.MONTH); // create variables
int year = time.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int DOM = time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int DOW = time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int hour = time.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int hourOfDay = time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = time.get(Calendar.SECOND);
long setMill = 1234567898765L;
String ampm = "";
String dayofw = "";
int am_pm = time.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

System.out.print(month + "/" + year + ", " + hour + ":" + minute + "." + second + " ");

switch (am_pm) {
    case  Calendar.AM:
        System.out.println("AM");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("PM");
        break;
}

System.out.println(month + "/" + year + ", " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute + "." + second + " " + (am_pm == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM"));
```

Outputs...

```
11/2013, 4:30.20 PM
11/2013, 16:30.20 PM
```

**Updated**

I'd be careful with using something like...

```
switch(DOW){ //switch statement to translate numeric value of DOW to string value
    case 1: dayofw = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 2: dayofw = "Monday";
        break;
    case 3: dayofw = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 4: dayofw = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 5: dayofw = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 6: dayofw = "Friday";
        break;
    case 7: dayofw = "Saturday";
        break;
}
```

As not all calendars start on the same day, instead, I'd be using something more like...

```
switch(DOW){ //switch statement to translate numeric value of DOW to string value
    case Calendar.SUNDAY: dayofw = "Sunday";
        break;
    .
    .    
    .
}
```

Comment: I did try using HOUR_OF_DAY, it displays the same thing for both of the methods. int hour = time.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); returns 00:27pm when I run it. I also dont understand why the pm doesn't change to am since it's past midnight right now.

Comment: I also tried this `am_pm = GregorianCalendar.AM_PM;
        if (am_pm == GregorianCalendar.AM){ 
            ampm = "am";
        }
        else {
            ampm = "pm";
        }` and nothing changed

Comment: As I said, `Calendar.AM_PM` is a parameter, not a value.  You need to use `Calendar#get(Calendar.AM_PM)` and examine the return result to determine the day part

Comment: Okay thanks for your help but even after setting my hour value to int `hour = time.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR);` it's still displaying 0 instead of 12. Also I've updated my code above with your method for the am_pm and now I'm just getting am for both results and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Take a read through the JavaDocs, `Calendar.HOUR` *"Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10"*

Comment: It's fine if you need to use a `switch` statement, but you need to getting the value from the `Calendar` before you try and compare it

Comment: I did this `if (hour == 0){
            hour = 12;
        }` to make it display the correct time at noon and midnight, however I still have a problem with the am_pm method. It displays that its am right now which is correct, however for the set time it should be pm and it's still displaying it as am.

Comment: Rather then using `GregorianCalendar` which is implementation of `Calendar`, try using `Calendar.getInstance()` which will return a `Calendar` implementation based on your current local

Comment: Our professor asked us to use the GregorianCalendar class for this project, so I can't change that unfortunately.

Comment: You set the `AM_PM` value `setTime.set(GregorianCalendar.AM_PM, GregorianCalendar.AM);` but never update the `am_pm` value, so it's still the same as it was when you first retrieved it from the first calendar

Comment: sorry, I didn't update my code. I made a new instance of AM_PM `int am_pm2 = time.get(GregorianCalendar.AM_PM);` because I didn't want the first one to carry over. Did I do it wrong? I figure it out, so sorry for being a drag. I didn't make this `int am_pm2 = setTime.get(GregorianCalendar.AM_PM);` before. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Dragged ourselves over the line in the end ;)